# Composer-1.5.5 does not work with php-7.2 on CentOS-7.4

Tags: php, composer-php, centos7, php-7.2

I have installed `PHP 7.2.0 (cli) (built: Dec 18 2017 09:57:10) ( NTS )` on `CentOS-7.4` and installed `composer-1.5.5` also.

When running `composer` on terminal, it throws below error:

`[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
  Command "list" is not defined.
  Did you mean this?
      list`

How can i fix it? thanks.

Comment: I changed `php` version to `php-7-1-12` and there is no problem with `composer-1.5.5` now. I think this problem is related to `php-7.2`.

Comment: Did you try the newest version? 1.5.6. If that doesn't work either, your best bet is to post an issue here: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues I'm afraid we really can't help you with this..

Comment: @walther No i did not try, as i said, i changed php's version and issue solved. As i work on a production server i can not change php's version to `7.2` again and test it with `composer-1.5.6`. Thank U for your response.

Answer (score 1):

The first step is always to test with the newest version, so in your case with composer 1.5.6 which was just released today.

You can always try it locally, no need to use a production server for that. If your local experiment tells you it works for php 7.2 + composer 1.5.5, you will know something's off on your server and you can work from there. If it works with composer 1.5.6, you'd know it will work on the production server and you don't have to fear about breaking something.

It's really just a standard way of doing things, as you shouldn't use a production server to test compatibility with newer versions of whatever software you're using.

If PHP 7.2 doesn't work with any composer version, you should probably create an issue for composer here: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues , as it would be probably some compatibility issue with the newest PHP release and we can't help you with that.

Comment: Locally on a `Windows-10` machine i have `PHP 7.2.0 (cli) (built: Nov 28 2017 23:48:49) ( ZTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x64 )` with `composer-1.5.5` and everything works fine. Locally i updated composer to `composer-1.5.6` and it works with `php-7.2` also. On the server maybe the problem is with `CentOs`.

Comment: Can you post the command that you're trying to use and append it to your question? Maybe that will help us determine what's wrong.

Comment: Command for what? when executing composer?? I said in my question that when running `composer` on terminal that error appears.